# C# programmatically communication with website

Tags: c#, web, communication, eisk

I have following problem.

Example site http://eisk.apphb.com/web-form-samples/listing-page.aspx

My c# application has to read data from gridview, but only for specific supervisor, so i need to change programmatically value in drop down list.

I have problem with change this value and get site with actually data in grid view.

Please help me solve this case.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I did something related in the past using Selenium, but now the changed the API and it's not so easy as it was before. (They merged Selenium with Web Driver)

You can see more about that in here:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp

You can also use Watin to do the same.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17064/WatiN-Web-Application-Testing-In-NET

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to download the site content then use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and get the data.

Comment: I use both of these but, i don't know how to change value in drop down list

Comment: When you change the value of the drop down list does it trigger a post?